# Subset R data frame by conditional values of one row

Tags: r

Ok so I'm stuck here...and fairly new to R.  I have a data frame that looks like the one below.

Let's say they're test scores by student...

```
set.seed(8675309)
name <- c('Bil', 'Sal', 'Kai', 'Kat', 'Jim', 'Xiu')
age <- c(7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 7)
HAVE <- data.frame(name, age, matrix(sample(100, 6*6, TRUE), ncol=6))
```

I want my code to do two things:

```
1. Given a name, find the best three "tests" for that student.
and...
2. Then pull all the data for only those three tests
```

For example, I want to look at Bil...

```
pick_name <- 'Bil'
```

I have tried using this piece of code that will pull the best test score for each student...though it doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
t3 <- colnames(HAVE)[max.col(HAVE[3:8], ties.method = 'first')]
t3 <- colnames(HAVE[which(HAVE$name==pick_name)])[max.col(HAVE[3:8], ties.method = 'first')]
```

Bil's best three tests are X2, X4, and X6, so my desired output should look like this:

```
WANT <- subset(HAVE, select = c(name, age, X2, X4, X6))
```

I'm more familiar with SAS, and the way I would do this is to pull the desired variables into a list and assign it to a macro variable, then subset based on the list of that macrovariable...but not sure how to do this in R.

Comment: I disagree...that question is looking at column specific operations, while mine is row specific. Furthermore, mine requires pulling Metadata  (column name) for one specific row, then using that to subset data.

Comment: In R, you can juggle multiple data sets. In this case, one with individuals (with attributes like age); and another with test results (reshaped so that they are on rows, not columns). From there, this is considerably simpler. "Row-specific" operations are pretty awkward and inefficient in R, since tables are stored columnwise...

Comment: Is it important that the shape of the data stays like this? If you `reshape2::melt` the dataframe, the problem is reduced to very basic filtering. For instance, `have <- melt(HAVE, id.vars = c("name", "age"))` reshapes the data, then `have <- have[order(have$value, decreasing = T),]` reorders it, and `have[have$name=="Bil",][1:3,]` gives you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find out the indices and subset directly. It would involve identifying the row with the given name (`HAVE$name == "Bil"`), order it in decreasing order (`order(..., decreasing = TRUE)`), accessing the first three indices (`[1:3]`) and sub-setting `HAVE` based on those values.

```
#-(1:2) to exclude the first two columns when ordering
#+2 at the end to account for -(1:2)
HAVE[, c(1:2, sort(order(HAVE[HAVE$name == "Bil",-(1:2)], decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]+2))]    
#  name age X2 X4 X6
#1  Bil   7 98 82 98
#2  Sal   8 85 72 85
#3  Kai   8 86  7 33
#4  Kat   9 45 85 60
#5  Jim   8 84 85 19
#6  Xiu   7 59 34 46

identical(WANT,
     HAVE[, c(1:2, sort(order(HAVE[HAVE$name == "Bil",-(1:2)], decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]+2))])
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to.  Thank you.  Trying to figure out how it is working....looks pretty slick.

Answer (score 1):

.. but there are no lists in SAS (?), a similar way to proc sql and proc transpose would be in my opinion (note that you have to install tidyr & dplyr):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
HAVE_long<-gather(HAVE,key="X",value="Score",X1:X6) # like proc transpose
Bil_score<-HAVE_long %>%    # a bit like proc sql
  filter(name=="Bil") %>%
  top_n(3,Score)
Bil_score
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is incomplete as it only returns the best three tests for a given student's name. It fails to  to meet the 2nd requirement of the OP (_Then pull all the data for only those three tests_).

Comment: select(HAVE,name,age,one_of(Bil_score[["X"]])) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are already two answers to this Q but both are IMHO *incomplete*.

Both work only for `"Bil"` (hard-coded!) and offer no general solution. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43742665/3817004) using `tidyr` and `dplyr` fails at all to meet the 2nd requirement of the OP (*Then pull all the data for only those three tests*).

The OP is looking for a SAS-like approach and mentions *lists* and *macro variables*.

#### Enhanced base R solution

The clever base R [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43741925/3817004) can be enhanced to return a list with the results for each possible `pick_name`:

```
result <- lapply(name, 
                 function(pick_name) {
                   HAVE[, c(1:2, sort(order(HAVE[HAVE$name == pick_name, -(1:2)], 
                                            decreasing = TRUE)[1:3] + 2))]
                 }
)
result <- setNames(result, name)

result
#$Bil
#  name age X2 X4 X6
#1  Bil   7 98 82 98
#2  Sal   8 85 72 85
#3  Kai   8 86  7 33
#4  Kat   9 45 85 60
#5  Jim   8 84 85 19
#6  Xiu   7 59 34 46
#
#$Sal
#  name age X2 X4 X6
#1  Bil   7 98 82 98
#2  Sal   8 85 72 85
#3  Kai   8 86  7 33
#4  Kat   9 45 85 60
#5  Jim   8 84 85 19
#6  Xiu   7 59 34 46
#
#$Kai
#  name age X1 X2 X3
#1  Bil   7 16 98 52
# ...
#$Xiu
#  name age X1 X2 X5
#1  Bil   7 16 98 56
#2  Sal   8 48 85 67
#3  Kai   8 77 86 26
#4  Kat   9 77 45  8
#5  Jim   8 27 84 16
#6  Xiu   7 68 59 82
```

`result` is a list (in R terminology) which contains for each `pick_name` a data frame with the data of the top 3 tests in comparison to all other names.
`lapply()` is a kind of "implied" `for` loop which runs over all elements of `name` returning a list. `setNames()` renames each element of the `result` list.

An individual list element can be picked either by number or by name. Thus,

```
result$Jim
result[[5]]
```

both return the same list element:

```
#  name age X2 X3 X4
#1  Bil   7 98 52 82
#2  Sal   8 85 27 72
#3  Kai   8 86 75  7
#4  Kat   9 45 92 85
#5  Jim   8 84 72 85
#6  Xiu   7 59 21 34
```

#### A more robust solution

The base R solution (although admittedly a clever one) is quite fragile as it makes implicit assumptions about number and position of columns in the initial `HAVE` data frame. It will fail if a column `gender` would be added, for instance. Or, if a different number of top tests need to be considered, e.g., the best 4 tests instead of the best 3.

The approach below is more robust as it uses column names. It requires only that the columns containing test results are consistently named by "X" followed by a number, eg., `X12`.

In order to make the process independent of number and position of relevant columns, the data are *reshaped from wide to long format*. In long format, the names of the tests (as given by the column names) are treated as data. For reshaping, `melt()` and `cast()` of the `data.table` package are used.

```
library(data.table)   # version 1.10.4. used
# reshape from wide to long
molten <- melt(as.data.table(HAVE), measure.vars =  patterns("^X\\d+$"))
```

The reshaped data look as follows:

```
molten
#    name age variable value
# 1:  Bil   7       X1    42
# 2:  Sal   8       X1    79
# 3:  Kai   8       X1     1
# 4:  Kat   9       X1    29
# 5:  Jim   8       X1    18
# 6:  Xiu   7       X1    77
# 7:  Bil   7       X2    93
# 8:  Sal   8       X2    32
# 9:  Kai   8       X2    18
# ...
#30:  Xiu   7       X5    95
#31:  Bil   7       X6    85
#32:  Sal   8       X6    10
#33:  Kai   8       X6    53
#34:  Kat   9       X6    97
#35:  Jim   8       X6    10
#36:  Xiu   7       X6    26
#    name age variable value
```

Finally, the list of results is created using `lapply()` and `setNames()` like the enhanced base R solution above.

```
# specify the number of top tests
n_top <- 3
result <- setNames(
  lapply(name, function(pick_name) {
    # get names of n_top best test results for pick_name
    cols <- molten[name == pick_name][order(-value), head(variable, n_top)]
    # reshape from long to wide but use only selected tests
    dcast(molten, name + age + gender ~ ..., subset = .(variable %in% cols))
  }), name
)
```

`result` is the same as shown above.